# Is it possible to override parts of an exisiting Spree factory?

Tags: factory-bot

I am building a Spree commerce application, and I'm using the factories provided by the gem in my specs. However, I find myself in the need to override some attributes for a specific factory to meet my application needs.

Example: the `User` factory defined by Spree has 6 characters for password. My applications demands at least 8. How can I override the `password` attribute without writing a whole new factory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow! Turns out I wasn't googling the right words. It's very easy in fact to [modify factories](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Modifying_factories), as specified in the docs.

```
FactoryGirl.modify do
  factory :user do
    password 'password
  end
end
```

In this particular situation, I had to make sure that Spree factories where being loaded before, by adding:

```
require 'spree/testing_support/factories'
```